# How to fix compile time error while implementing sliding menu using jeremyfeinstein library in android

Tags: android, android-menu, android-sliding

I have downloaded the sliding menu project from [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) link.

I have imported the project in eclipse.

I am getting the following compile time error:

```
**com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockPreferenceActivity**
```

I am getting above  `class is not available`. Can anybody tell me if there is any jar file I need to add? Could you provide a link to it if possible?

Thanks

Comment: use `NavigationDrawer` instead with support library

Comment: @Raghunandan sliding effect will not come using like face book and gamil navigateion Drawer

Comment: gmail uses navigation drawer

Comment: @Raghunandan yes facebook and gmail like menu and sliding effect

Comment: its a library project you to reference the same. its dependent on actionbarsherlock so you need that also. You should use navigation drawer instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll strictly recommended you to use android support library v7.

Find more :

http://blog.xamarin.com/android-support-library-v7-hello-actionbarcompat/http://blog.xamarin.com/android-support-library-v7-hello-actionbarcompat/

if you don't want it

1 . right click your project ->properties->android

```
   in that make sure you have all lib added as reference.
```

1. clean your project : project->clean.
2. make sure your sliding menu lib also have reference to  ActionBarSherlock Project Lib.

Comment: still am getting compile error in this package com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu

Comment: it is compile time error com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu this packaage class is not available

Comment: try to add project build path via  : rightclick on project ->properties ->java build path -> projects tab -> [add sliding menu as reference] ->order and export ->check sliding menu -> clean ->done ??